# C# - Timer System For Game (Ex. Clash of Clans)

Tags: .net, events

I am trying to design, in C#, something similar to the way that games like Clash of Clans use timers when you build stuff. So I thought about it quite a bit but I am really stumped.

I am not really sure how to design this. Would I use the Timer class in the .Net Framework? If so, the API seems to confuse me a bit about how I can set up the timer and then set up a second timer if I am building two things at a time (in the example at least). Or perhaps there is better way than a timer...

To be as direct as possible I guess I am asking how can I design a system that takes time for things to happen after something like a button click?

I want to try to get a skeleton using a console app so I can keep things simple.

Comment: I removed the opening line and your salutation at the end as we tend to be more to-the-point on Stack Overflow compared to other forum sites.

Comment: Use the [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class which will give you a `TimeSpan` via the `Elapsed` Property.  You can use that to determine how much time has passed and decide the status/percentage of whatever is currently being built.  If you want to speed up or slow down time then you simply use a factor of the current elapsed time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid mucking about with timers - they would certainly do the job, but they will end up creating a lot of event handling code that will quickly get confusing to work with.

Instead I would look at using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main", "Rx-WPF", or "Rx-WinForms") to do your timing.

Here's the main method you'd need:

```
public IObservable<int> Builder(int seconds)
{
    var step = 5;
    return
        Observable
            .Generate(
                0,
                x => x <= 100,
                x => x + 5,
                x => x,
                x => TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)seconds * (double)step / 100.0));
}
```

This lets you create an observable that will return integers for you from 0 to 100, stepping by 5 (which you could change), and produces values for a total of `seconds` seconds.

This is the code that you'd use to consume it:

```
var subscription =
    Builder(3)
        .Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Done!"));

Console.ReadLine();
```

You'll see that the `.Subscribe` method lets you respond to each value as it is produced and you get a handy "Done!" handler when it is finished.

If you need to stop the subscription before the time runs out - if the user hits cancel, for example - then just call `.Dispose()` on the `subscription` variable.

Now, you probably need to marshall the events to the UI thread. That's easy to do. Assuming you're using Windows Forms then you code would look like this:

```
var subscription =
    Builder(3)
        .ObserveOn(someControlOrForm)
        .Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Done!"));
```

Here's the output.

```
0
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50
55
60
65
70
75
80
85
90
95
100
Done!
```

Simple.

---

In the comments, Blindy asked why this is any better than normal event handlers. Here's an example.

Say I had a list of picture boxes (`List<PictureBox>`) that I wanted to update, and I wanted the updates to have different random times, I could do it this way:

```
var query =
    from pb in pictureBoxes.ToObservable()
    from n in Builder(rnd.Next(2, 6))
    select new { pb, n };

var subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOn(someControlOrForm)
        .Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine("{0} has value {1}", x.pb, x.n),
            () => Console.WriteLine("Done!"));
```

All items in the list, randomly updated, in effectively two lines of code.

Comment: How's this any simpler to work with than just a `Tick` event handler?

Comment: @Blindy - You can run as many as you want independently of each other. There's no need to detach event handlers - that's done for you. It automatically marshalls to the UI thread. You can join, filter, and project the queries against each other. You can take advantage of 100's of other operators provided to work with observables. You can encapsulate the queries within a single method so you don't have to have event handlers as separate methods.

Comment: @Blindy - I've added a more powerful example for you to look at.

Comment: I didn't ask why it was any better, I already know why it is. I asked how is this any simpler for what he wants.

Comment: @Blindy, Oh, sorry. It's just simpler because it encapsulates the state, logic, the handling, and the clean-up all in one place, effectively.

Comment: I've really got to start using rx. Keep putting it off due to the docs being so convoluted or difficult to follow each time I try to read through them heh.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger - Yes, Rx is awesome. If you are doing any UI work you just need to create a few extension methods that turns the `Click` event into the `Clicks` observable and you're off. It's just amazing. Drag-and-drop is almost a one-liner. It's one of the most powerful libraries Microsoft has ever produced.

Comment: Are the subscriptions to those events weak references? Or am I going to leak if I don't dispose of a subscription on an event?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger - Observables automatically dispose themselves when they complete (or end on an error). You only have to dispose if you want the sequence to end early. As for sequences based on events, since they infinite you need to dispose of them just as you would need to detach handlers. The nice thing is you can add multiple disposables to a `CompositeDisposable` and have a single way to dispose of many subscriptions. Much easier to manage.